# What is wrong in this Prolog clause?

Tags: prolog

I need to write clauses in prolog that express the following sentence

> "Everyone is mortal but john"

here are my clauses:

```
not(mortal(john)).

mortal(_).
```

but when I query `?- mortal(john).` it returns true instead false.

What is wrong?

Comment: `mortal(_).` means anyone is mortal. And your facts contradict one another (you're saying both are facts). You need something like, `mortal(X) :- X \= john.` (`X` is mortal if `X` is not `john`). The "fact" `not(mortal(john)).` is not the correct way to express the fact about john's mortality or lack thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it.

You have two facts:-

```
not(mortal(john)).
mortal(_).
```

Running the query `?- mortal(john).` cannot bind against the first fact as it is not structurally the same, but it can bind against the second.